# Double page requests when using history.js

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, history.js, singlepage

We have created a single page application in MVC4 and are using history.js to provide forwards and backwards functionality. But, a curious thing is happening: whenever a link is clicked in our site, the request is made twice. As near as I can tell, this was caused by using history.js to push page requests.

On to the code:

In the shared _Layout.cshtml, we have placed this script tag that handles all of the history.js interaction.

```
    $(function () {
        var History = window.History;

        // Bind to StateChange Event
        History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() { // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
            var State = History.getState(); 
            Helper.GetPartial(State.data.URL, State.data.PANEL, State.data.INITIAL, State.data.TITLE, State.data.DATA, State.data.CALLBACK, true);
        });
```

We have implemented a script that encapsulates all of our ajax methods to get the partial pages and swap out the content:

```
    GetPartial: function (url, panel, initialElement, title, data, callBack, historyTriggered) {
        $("#bg").mask("Loading...");
        getHtml("../" + url, data, function (result) {
            if (!historyTriggered) {
                var stateObj = { URL: url, DATA: data, TITLE: title, PANEL: panel, INITIAL: initialElement, CALLBACK: callBack };
                window.History.pushState(stateObj, title, title);
            }
            transition(panel, initialElement, title, result); //just doing jquery transitions here.
            callBack = callBack || function () { };
            callBack();
            $("#bg").unmask();
        });
    },
```

And here is the code for getHtml:

```
var getHtml = function(url, data, callBack) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        success: callBack
    });
},
```

So, my question is, what are we doing wrong that is causing two requests every time a link within our site is clicked?

Comment: Is it possible that the Ajax request is made before a normal, synchronous HTTP request for the same content? If so, perhaps you need to add a preventDefault type call. Can you provide the list of requests from Chrome Dev tools (or similar)?

Comment: There are no synchronous HTTP requests being made. Once logged into the app, all requests are sent through ajax gets or posts.

Comment: Maybe something is triggering another statechange. Is there any way to tell how many times the URI changes?

Comment: Well, as near as I can tell, the URL only changes once. However, if I put a breakpoint in the controller action that I'm going to be calling from an ajax request, it gets hit twice. That's really the most definitive evidence I have about what is going on. It just doesn't make sense to me why it would be hitting the target controller action twice.